# Failure of "try" not going to "catch" block

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

This code is written to get the error reported in console if `WebElement` is not found on page. It fails on try block but doesn't go to catch. 
I have tried different tweaks and tricks but its not working, please share what am I missing:

Code:

```
public class GetElement extends TestBase{


WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

public WebElement getElement(WebElement element) {
    try {
        System.out.println("\n" + "==============" + "\n"
                + "inside try of gE" + "\n" + "===================");
        return wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException  ex) {
        System.out.println("\n" + "==============" + "\n"
                + element.getText()
                + " Element not or wasnt clickable found on page" + "\n"
                + driver.getCurrentUrl() + "\n" + "===================");

    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "==============" + "\n"
            + "Element will be returned as null"+ "\n" + "===================");
    return null;
}

}
```

here `TestBase` initializes the `WebDriver`

Exception that I get often is (often, because I was also getting time out but then I increased time):

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=38.0.2125.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 137 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
```

Comment: Please show the exception you get.

Comment: Share the exception you got .. you may not catch the right Exception.

Comment: You are not catching NoSuchElementException. Add catch (NoSuchElementException e) or catch (Exception e) (for any exception).

Comment: Where does the exception you show get printed? Did you try debugging?

Comment: which java are you using? multi-catch works only in java 7 and above

Comment: you might be catching a different NoSuchElementException, check the imports make sure its org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Thanks Hagai it worked,I changed it JRE 1.7 and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Several possobilities.

1. The exception thrown is `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`. Because `NoSuchElementException` is a fairly common name, I suspect in your code the `NoSuchElementException` isn't from your `org.openqa.selenium` package.
2. The exception is thrown from outside of the try block at all.

If you still cannot work out where it's from, add a catch block to catch all `Exception` after and see if the exception is correctly triggered in your try block.

Comment: This isn't the answer. Where do yo see that its not from selenium package. Anyways its resolved, read Hagai's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

What Alex said is right, your catch block catches `java.util.NoSuchElementException` - from , but you must be actually getting a

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.
```

Try this catch block:

```
catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e| TimeoutException  ex){
```